# Stripping '$'-sign from sales list

Tags: python, list, strip

Why am I unable to strip '$' in the first method of code however I am able to strip in the second method?

**Method 1**

```
sales = ['$1.21', '$7.29', '$12.52', '$5.13', '$20.39', '$30.82', '$1.85', '$17.98', '$17.41', '$28.59']

for element in sales:
 element.strip('$')

 print(element)
```

**Method 2**

```
sales = ['$1.21', '$7.29', '$12.52', '$5.13', '$20.39', '$30.82', '$1.85', '$17.98', '$17.41', '$28.59']

for element in sales:

 print(element.strip('$'))
```

Comment: In the first one you ignore the return value of `strip`.

Comment: because you are not storing the return value of `element.strip('$')` anywhere.
In the second case you are just seeing the result of the strip, but the strip is not applied to the elements in the list `sales`. If you want to modify the list sales by stripping the `$` sign, you would have to create a new list with the modified elements.

Comment: `sales = [i.lstrip('$') for i in sales]`, `sales[:] = (i.lstrip('$') for i in sales)`

Comment: The second one should work if you format it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[str.strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method does not modify given string, instead it returns the result as it is specified in official documentation.

> Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters
> removed.

Since `element.strip('$')` returns result instead of modifying `element` this code does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the variable in the for loop and use indexing if you want to change the original list:

```py
sales = ['$1.21', '$7.29', '$12.52', '$5.13', '$20.39', '$30.82', '$1.85', '$17.98', '$17.41', '$28.59']

for x in range(len(sales)):
    sales[x] = sales[x].strip('$')
    print(sales[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you'd like to treat sales as a numeric variable

```
sales = ['$1.21', '$7.29', '$12.52', '$5.13', '$20.39', '$30.82', '$1.85', '$17.98', '$17.41', '$28.59']


sales = [float(element.strip('$')) for element in sales]
```

Then you could either print it or sum it

```
print("total sales: {t:.2f}".format(t=sum(sales)))
```

Comment: doing currency calculations with floats is fraught with danger. - for example in most languages `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 != 0.3` due to imprecission in floating point values. Far better to convert them to cents as soon as you can.

sales = [element.strip('$') for element in sales]

Comment: It could happen that python will add *.000000123* at the end of the sum, so it'll be good to format output ;) Or use `Decimal`.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66, note taken - updated my answer to account for floating point precision

Comment: @OlvinRoght it WILL happen because in Python and most other languages floats are imprecise

Comment: @UriGoren not really - even fsum can't get round the fact that floats can't store 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 etc accurately and you will still get rounding errors

Comment: interesting, I thought that was it's whole purpose

Comment: @UriGoren, it COULD happen.

Comment: @UriGoren, you're performing useless calculations, `.2f` does all job, so you don't need to multiply each item to get value in cents, just leave it like it is. `print("total sales: {:.2f}".format(sum(float(i.lstrip("$")) for i in sales)))`

Comment: @OlvinRoght and on a large list the rounding errors in floats can sum to more than 0.01 - which means that your total is now wrong. Unless you are dealing with very large values don't use floats for curency.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I’m curious as to why method 1 does not strip ‘$’?

Comment: @TonySuffolk66, I agree with you, `Decimal` is better, but I should notice that you'd rather overflow your ram with such as list which could cause rounding error.

Comment: @t92, it does, but you don't save result.

Comment: @olvin - a small list would do it think writh the right chosen values. You don't even need decimal - just strip off the '$' and remove the '.' and you have the value in cents - no rounding errors etc.

Comment: It all depends on the range of the values - as the max of the values to be summed increases the imprecision increases. I agree that the a very small list of very small values (such as the example) wont cause an error - but I believe in also teaching good habits, and using float on currency is a bad habit.

Answer (score 0):

To convert it into cents (don't ever do currency work with floats since floats are imprecise, you can do this :

```
sales_in_cents =  [int(element.strip('$').replace('.','')) for element in sales]
```

To show the total in $ ...

```
print(f'Total sales : {sum(sales_in_cents)/100:0.2f}'
```

Do all of your calculations (including your sums) with cents and convert to $ (by dividing by 100  only when you need to do so.